# VBA Excel 2011 for Mac: Create custom category for user defined function error

Tags: macos, microsoft-excel, vba, macros, microsoft-excel-2011

I created several functions i.e.: "cal_adval". I would like to add it to a new function category named "Custom Clearance"

I read [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838997%28v=office.14%29.aspx), and wrote this macro:

```
Sub add_category()

Application.MacroOptions Macro:="calc_adval", Category:="Customs Clearance"
Application.MacroOptions Macro:="calc_fodinfa", Category:="Customs Clearance"
Application.MacroOptions Macro:="calc_vat", Category:="Customs Clearance"
Application.MacroOptions Macro:="calc_liquidation", Category:="Customs Clearance"

End Sub
```

However I got this error: `Method MacroOption of application failed`. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

I'm thinking the error you're getting is:

> Method 'MacroOptions' of object '_Application' failed

This is an indication that one of the macros that you're trying to add to the category, doesn't exist. Double check they exist and double check the spelling.

Comment: When I use the exact same code with `Category:= 1` the macro executes correctly and the functions are all added to "Finance". The problem occurs only when I use a customized name for `Category:=`

Comment: @Ruben the code you pasted compiles perfectly for me, when I have the functions in that code defined. Doesn't matter if they are in different modules. Are yours in sheet objects by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

I ran the code in Excel 2013 for Windows, and it worked perfectly. Chances are this is related to the OS and Excel  version.